# Exceptions and Output in Java

Tags: java, exception

I would like to be able to tell for sure when the compiler throws an exception **with no output** and when it's going to execute a few lines of code **followed by an exception**.

To further illustrate my point, consider the following code:

```
public class OverAndOver {
   static String s = "";
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
       s += "1";
       throw new Exception();
     } catch (Exception e) { s += "2";
     } finally { s += "3"; doStuff(); s += "4";
     }
     System.out.println(s);
   }
   static void doStuff() { int x = 0; int y = 7/x; }
 }
```

A quick glance at the doStuff() method and you know the compiler is going to throw a Divide-by-zero exception.

Now, here's my question though (and the source of my confusion): Why didn't the compiler displayed "123" followed by the exception? And most importantly, how can I be able to tell for sure when the compiler is going to execute a few lines of code before throwing an exception and when it's going to throw an exception right away with no output?

Comment: Side point: probably you mean runtime environment, compiler doesn't execute your code.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. +1

Answer (score 4):

> Why didn't the compiler displayed "123" followed by the exception?

First of all, the compiler doesn't execute the code, so it will never display those values.

If you wonder why your app didn't display the text before the exception, the answer is that you didn't print it: you just append it to a string, and you print the string **after** the `finally` block.

The `finally` block throws an exception and your print statement will never be reached.

Try to print the text directly:

```
public class OverAndOver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("1");
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("2");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("3");
            doStuff();
            System.out.println("4");
        }
    }

    static void doStuff() {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 7 / x;
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
1
2
3
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.jedisoftware.lf_delivery_tracking.OverAndOver.doStuff(App.java:74)
    at com.jedisoftware.lf_delivery_tracking.OverAndOver.main(App.java:67)
```

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation. I tried to accept your post as an answer but it didn't allow me. I'll try again later. Once again, thanks a lot.

Comment: One last question: are there any exceptions  in Java where, regardless of your code, the runtime environment throws solely the exception with no output?

Comment: @JesseJames Java is like any other language: It does exactly what you tell it to do. Exception will break the execution of the program if not caught and handled, but they will not "wipe" the program output. Everything you print before the exception gets printed.

Comment: @JesseJames Regarding accepting the answer, You need to wait a certain time before you can accept answers (I think it's about 15 minutes since you posted the question)

Answer (score 1):

> Why didn't the compiler displayed "123" followed by the exception?

Because `System.out.println(s);` instruction is never executed.. Exception is raised in the `doStuff();` method and the execution of main method is interrupted.
If you want to display `123` before the exception you should put the `System.out.println(s);` instruction before the `doStuff()` method as follows:

```
public class OverAndOver {
   static String s = "";
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
       s += "1";
       throw new Exception();
     } catch (Exception e) { s += "2";
     } finally { s += "3"; System.out.println(s); doStuff(); s += "4";
     }
   }
   static void doStuff() { int x = 0; int y = 7/x; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `doStuff()` which may throw an unchecked exception outside of a try block. If you want to print both the exception and the string you must wrap the `doStuff()` call in a try-catch construct.

```
public class OverAndOver {
   static String s = "";
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
       s += "1";
       throw new Exception();
     } catch (Exception e) { s += "2";
     } finally {
        try{
          s += "3"; doStuff(); s += "4";
       }catch(ArithmeticException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
     System.out.println(s);
   }
   static void doStuff() { int x = 0; int y = 7/x; }
 }
```